# Android: problems with floor plans in Android MapView

Tags: android, navigation, android-mapview

Now google Maps also has got floor plans (http://googlemobile.blogspot.de/2011/11/go-indoors-with-google-maps-60-for.html).

Are they already proper assisted by the Android MapView?

Specially is ist possible to:

1) automatically zoom to floor plan zoom level?

2) set via code the current floor plan level

3) Listener when the User changes the floor plan level manually

thx for every help

Comment: Can you please check this [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N25MxHZ9dDE) and give me clue or guide me or help me to find tutorials. I'm trying to place some objects on real world coordinates through Android camera when I click.